# Calculating TCP Header Length?

Tags: networking, tcp, frame, wireshark, network-protocols

Can anyone guide me on the following?

I'm trying to figure out the answer as seen in the first question inside the blog malwarejake[.]blogspot.com/2015/05/packet-analysis-practice-part-3.html .

As per sample packet found

What is the embedded protocol, the destination port, and the amount of data not including protocol headers?

```
    0x0000:  4500 004c 1986 4000 4006 9cba c0a8 0165
    0x0010:  c0a8 01b6 0015 bf3c dad0 5039 2a8c 25be
    0x0020:  8018 0072 06ec 0000 0101 080a 008a 70ac
```

The answer for the above question is as above.

```
    Embedded protocol: TCP
    Total packet length:  76
    IP Header length:  20
    Protocol header length: 32
    Data length: 24
    Dest Port: 0xbf3c (48956)
```

I managed to get all the other answer with the exception of **Protocol Header Length** and **Data Length**.

Isn't TCP Header Length normally 20 bytes with the extension up to 40 bytes? But how is 32 bytes derived from the above packet? I don't understand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the TCP Header directly from the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793):

```
    0                   1                   2                   3
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |          Source Port          |       Destination Port        |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                        Sequence Number                        |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    Acknowledgment Number                      |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |  Data |           |U|A|P|R|S|F|                               |
   | Offset| Reserved  |R|C|S|S|Y|I|            Window             |
   |       |           |G|K|H|T|N|N|                               |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |           Checksum            |         Urgent Pointer        |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                    Options                    |    Padding    |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
   |                             data                              |
   +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

The values `0015` and `bf3c` are the ports.
The values `dad0 5039` and `2a8c 25be` are the sequence/ack numbers.

Now take a look at the next 4 bits. The ones at offset `0x20`. The value of the byte is `0x80`, which means that the topmost 4 bits are `1000`. They correspond to the "data offset" field:

> Data Offset:  4 bits
>
> The number of 32 bit words in the TCP Header.  This indicates where
> the data begins.  The TCP header (even one including options) is an
> integral number of 32 bits long.

So `1000` means that the header consists of 8 x 32-bit words, which means 8 x 4 bytes = 32 bytes.

Comment: Hello Malt, Greatly Appreciate. Totally understood it.